# Smart explode or something other

Tags: php

I have array:

```
$array = [
    'aaa 3',
    'bbb 15',
    'ccccc 3A',
    'dddd 2412',
    'eee fff 15',
    'ggg 612',
    'hhh iiiii 23B',
];
```

I would like receive:

```
$name = 'aaa'; $number = '3';
$name = 'bbb'; $number = '15';
$name = 'ccccc'; $number = '3A';
$name = 'dddd'; $number = '2412';
$name = 'eee'; $number = '15';
$name = 'ggg'; $number = '612';
$name = 'hhh iiiii'; $number = '23B';
```

So I do:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $expl = explode(' ', $item);
    $name = $expl[0];
    $number = $expl[1];
}
```

But this not working for `eee fff 15` and `hhh iiiii 23B`, because these names has two parts. How is better way for this?

Comment: If array size is more than 2 - implode items.

Comment: With the expected output you'd just overwrite your values.

Comment: why `'eee fff 15',` =>$name = 'eee'; $number = '15';`  but `'hhh iiiii 23B',=>$name = 'hhh iiiii'; $number = '23B';`? don't you think it should be:-`'hhh iiiii 23B',=>$name = 'hhh'; $number = '23B';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
<?php

$array = [
    'aaa 3',
    'bbb 15',
    'ccccc 3A',
    'dddd 2412',
    'eee fff 15',
    'ggg 612',
    'hhh iiiii 23B',
];

$regex = '#(?<word>.+)\s(?<number>.+)#';
$results = [];

foreach ($array as $line) {
    preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
    $results[$matches['word']] = $matches['number'];
}

var_dump($results);
```

2 capture groups, first is any characters `.+`, then a space `\s`, then any characters `.+`

Output:

```
array(7) { ["aaa"]=> string(1) "3" ["bbb"]=> string(2) "15" ["ccccc"]=> string(2) "3A" ["dddd"]=> string(4) "2412" ["eee fff"]=> string(2) "15" ["ggg"]=> string(3) "612" ["hhh iiiii"]=> string(3) "23B" }
```

See it working here: https://3v4l.org/t2tMd

Comment: Depends on the data - but there are issues if you have '2aaa 1B' or 'aaaa 1 1B'

Comment: Indeed, but those weren't mentioned in his use cases, so I didn't take it as a requirement. It's pretty trivial to tweak the regex for that though.

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to use immediate examples they have to hand, but then two hours down the line when it starts to go wrong in the wild they suddenly change what their requirements are.

Comment: Which is why you have to sometimes try and predict this churn, why code something which has artificial limits?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the size of the array and pick only the last for the number and the rest for the name...

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $expl = explode(' ', $item);
    $name = implode(" ", array_slice($expl,0,-1));
    $number = $expl[count($expl)-1];

    echo $name."=". $number.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $expl = explode(' ', $item);
    $division=array_pop($expl);
    $name = $expl[0].' '.$expl[1];
    $number = $division;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but I wanted to throw in my suggestion on how to do this. 
If the `$number` you want is always at the end of the array, then it doesn't matter how big `$name` is

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $expl = explode(' ', $item);
    //get the size of the array
    $last= count($expl)-1;

    //get the final element in the array
    $number = $expl[$last];

    //remove the last element from array
    unset($expl[$last]);

    //glue it back together
    $name = implode(" ",$expl);

    //set the name + number in our array
    $newArray[]=array('name' => $name,'number'=>$number);

}


print_r($newArray);

//Output:
/* Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [name] => aaa 
            [number] => 3 
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
            [name] => bbb 
            [number] => 15 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [name] => ccccc 
            [number] => 3A 
        ) 
        [3] => Array (
            [name] => dddd 
            [number] => 2412 
        ) 
        [4] => Array ( 
            [name] => eee fff 
            [number] => 15 
        ) 
        [5] => Array ( 
            [name] => ggg 
            [number] => 612 
        ) 
        [6] => Array ( 
            [name] => hhh iiiii 
            [number] => 23B 
        )       
    ) 
*/
```